# How to make complex charts using Raphael

Tags: raphael

I supposed to make this type of charts, is it posssible to make through Raphael or any good Plug-in for Raphael. ( i prefer raphael, because already i using this), I am attaching the image that what i need to produce?

[image]

thanks for advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd genuinely advise just drawing the thing manually using the Raphael library. When we had a requirement for an uncommon graph type, I attempted to get existing graphing libraries to draw it, but it was awful. I mocked up a prototype in an evening to demonstrate how much cleaner it is to draw it manually with raphael, and we ended up using it. Best thing you can try to do is prototype what you are looking for: create a dummy set of Json for the graph and try to plot from this data. You should find that it's relatively straight forward to divide the content area up:

```
numberOfMonths = 6;
barsPerMonth = 2;
marginLeft = 40;
marginRight = 40;

graphArea = canvasWidth - marginLeft - marginRight;
monthWidth = graphArea /  numberOfMonths;
barWidth = monthWidth / barsPerMonth;
```

Just define all of the margins and widths that you want. Define the range of your axes and define a tick scale/count. That should get you started.